# laravel hydrateRaw/fromQuery and eager loading with pagination

Tags: laravel-5.4, eager-loading, laravel-pagination

I currently found out that you can hydrate an Raw sql query.

I have following query:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(SELECT *, Y(location) AS longitude, X(location) AS latitude FROM meetings WHERE MBRCONTAINS(@quadrat, location)) AS sub'))
            ->select(DB::raw('(FLOOR(SQRT(POW((@ibk_breite - sub.latitude) * 111, 2) + POW((@ibk_laenge - sub.longitude) * 111 * ABS(COS(RADIANS(@ibk_breite))),2)))) AS distance, sub.*, latitude, longitude'));
```

which I hydrate as following

```
$meetings = Meeting::fromQuery($query->toSql());
```

In the blade view i need to get some additional data from different tables, for example:

```
 $meeting->user
```

which references to the User Model. But if I'm not complety wrong that would result to a n+1 problem in a for each loop, because I'm not eager loading it?! So is it possible to eager load the required models as you would normally do with

```
->with('user', 'books', 'etc...')
```

??

Also is it possible to paginate it like  `$meetings = $query->paginate(5);` and do `$meetings->withPath('home');`

EDIT:
Found a solution:

```
// Do your query stuff
 // Get count before the query because it won't work with skip and take     parameter
    $count = $query->count();

    $query->skip($skip);
    $query->take($meetingsPerPage);
    $meetings = Meeting::fromQuery($query->toSql());
    $meetings->load('user', 'interest.image', 'img_thumbnail');
    $meetings = new LengthAwarePaginator($meetings, $count, $meetingsPerPage);
```

`$meetings->load` acts as `->with()`. 
As last step you need to create a paginator. IMPORTANT: Use `query->count()` before you set `skip()` and/or `take()` Otherwise it will not work.

Original answer from [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hydraterawfromquery-with-pagination). Theres also another possibily stated that didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Very good question

Comment: I asked in another forum and got this part of answer [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hydraterawfromquery-with-pagination)

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: @Ronon You have no idea how much frustration this just saved me

Comment: @Ronon It would be better if you add your answer as a actual answer and mark it as accepted instead of providing the answer in the question. See [self answer documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
// Do your query stuff
// Get count before the query because it won't work with skip and take parameter
$count = $query->count();

$query->skip($skip);
$query->take($meetingsPerPage);
$meetings = Meeting::fromQuery($query->toSql());
$meetings->load('user', 'interest.image', 'img_thumbnail');
$meetings = new LengthAwarePaginator($meetings, $count, $meetingsPerPage);
```

`$meetings->load` acts as `->with()`. As last step you need to create a paginator. IMPORTANT: Use `query->count()` before you set `skip()` and/or `take()` Otherwise it will not work.

Original answer from [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hydraterawfromquery-with-pagination). Theres also another possibily stated that didn't work for me.

Comment: Awsm! The Eloquent collection "load()" method is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use setCollection() function with LengthAwarePaginator object (found in  Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php). Use load() for eager loading.

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->paginate();
 $users->setCollection(User::hydrate($users->items())->load(['category']));
```